# When should I use ACL in my application

Tags: security, permissions, acl

**I am pretty much confused as to when I should implement an ACL (access control list) system in my application** though I can easily manage permissions on groups simply by fetching the session group id and restricting the access using the Auth component.

How is an ACL solution better then the approach I discussed above (restricting the group access based on group id) ?

How does implementing an ACL solution simplify things when it comes to managing access rights in your application ?

Till now I have learned that through ACL, permissions can be granted and revoked at runtime, but this functionality is also achievable without using an ACL.

I am very much confused about this, please help me understand the concept, when to use ACL and the benefits of using ACL in your web application.

I prefer to code with cakePHP v1.3 so it would be great if the explanation is given in context of cakephp but any help (language/technology independent) related to my question is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must use ACLs (or an  equivalent user permission mechanism such as literal database User and Permission tables) rather than groups if you need to control access to individual entities **which vary dynamically**. File systems attach ACL's to individual files since you don't want to create a separate group for each file. Database managers attach ACL's to databases, tables, views, stored procedures and whatnot for the same reason. Web servers deal with web applications in the same manner.

In a business application dealing with business entities, you may want to partition access to entities such as e.g. different sales orders, customers, products or divisions within your company, where not everybody is allowed to create/update or even read the same entities. For instance, when sales staff are in direct competition for bonuses, they don't want everybody else to see all the information on their CRM-stored prospects.

Usually, though, you want to keep your access mechanisms as coarse-grained as is humanly possible: groups are usually good enough. Fine-grained access control mechanisms have a tendency to grow complex, expensive, inaccurate and hard to use correctly. They may even **decrease** security, since administrative frustration encourages people to find clever workarounds...

Comment: Good recommendation on keeping access as coarse-grained as possible

Answer (score 1):

I think that ACL technic for securising user access to ressources is usefull only for a typical or medium - sized application . for big applications like CRM or financial data warehouses , ACLs will fail to manage a very complex set of user / ressource couples , when the data increase in size , in type and in volume , the ACLs tables made for that purpose will increase too , which it make for me no sense to overload the database server with ACL Tables. There are many others technics used to install security access and permissions and privileges ... The use of ACL files instead does not sound bad but it is not a good idea as files may corrupt from time to time so data failure is over the risk to not have access to a file containing ACL rules or to access a non existing file or a lost one ... The only way to play with permission is to use the business tables used in the context or in the purpose of your application with relationships between your tables and some logic to add to your Service Side Scripts if you are under MVC Architecture or any else ... So Avoid using ACL for very big sized applications.